# gulp.js - dest.on is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, sass, gulp, gulp-sass

I am attempting to compile my `styles.scss` with `gulp-sass` when I recieve the following error:

```
[09:48:49] Starting 'e'...
[09:48:49] 'e' errored after 2.35 ms
[09:48:49] TypeError: dest.on is not a function
    at DestroyableTransform.Readable.pipe (D:\Data\Web Development\Repositories\ds-www\node_modules\through2\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_readable.js:485:8)
    at Gulp.<anonymous> (D:\Data\Web Development\Repositories\ds-www\gulpfile.js:44:6)
    at module.exports (D:\Data\Web Development\Repositories\ds-www\node_modules\orchestrator\lib\runTask.js:34:7)
    at Gulp.Orchestrator._runTask (D:\Data\Web Development\Repositories\ds-www\node_modules\orchestrator\index.js:273:3)
    at Gulp.Orchestrator._runStep (D:\Data\Web Development\Repositories\ds-www\node_modules\orchestrator\index.js:214:10)
    at D:\Data\Web Development\Repositories\ds-www\node_modules\orchestrator\index.js:279:18
    at finish (D:\Data\Web Development\Repositories\ds-www\node_modules\orchestrator\lib\runTask.js:21:8)
    at module.exports (D:\Data\Web Development\Repositories\ds-www\node_modules\orchestrator\lib\runTask.js:60:3)
    at Gulp.Orchestrator._runTask (D:\Data\Web Development\Repositories\ds-www\node_modules\orchestrator\index.js:273:3)
    at Gulp.Orchestrator._runStep (D:\Data\Web Development\Repositories\ds-www\node_modules\orchestrator\index.js:214:10)
```

I have `gulp-sass` installed in another project and works correctly - with the same `gulpfile.js` which means it must be a problem with in the `node_modules` folder.

Here is the `gulpfile.js` for reference:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');

gulp.task('e', function(){
  gulp.src('app/admin/assets/sass/*.scss') // ## Not working
    .pipe(sass())
    .pipe('dist/admin/assets/css');
});

gulp.task('default', ['e'], function(){
  console.log('Gulp tasks started!');
});
```

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your destination should be written like :

```
gulp.task('e', function(){
  gulp.src('app/admin/assets/sass/*.scss') // ## Not working
    .pipe(sass())
    .pipe( gulp.dest('dist/admin/assets/css') );
});
```

In order to pipe properly to your destination folder.

Comment: Oh... That's awkward. I never realised that - thanks a lot! :)